# Joomla 3.3 Custom Extension allowing browser cache

Tags: php, caching, joomla

I have recently ported a Joomla custom extension to 3.3.x that I originally wrote for 1.3 and have had running on 2.x for many years.

It is a standard extension that presents a list of records that show various fields for each record. The user clicks on one and a form showing the listed fields and others. User updates values and clicks Save and Close. The record saves correctly, but the browser does not refresh the previous page but simply re-displays the original. The consequence is that User thinks it hasn't worked, clicks on said record a second time and brings up form with correct (as in updated in first attempt) values. The now frustrated user blames programmer.

For very good and unavoidable reasons, at the same time I ported the site to Joomla 3.3, I also had to move from an in-house managed server to a Zen hosted one. I have several other clients on Zen and have not experienced this problem, so I suspect my user is right to blame the programmer.

I can't find anything relating to caching and custom extensions and the site setting for cache is OFF. The template uses the JAT3 plugin, but has done so for at least four years. There was an update to this as part of the Joomla upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates using the JAT3 plugin use their own cache. You can check their settings if cache is enabled or not. Another thing that you should check is the error_log .

Comment: HI, I tried changing the template to a non- JAT3 plugin one and the problem went away. The settings suggested that the cache was off, but that seems to be the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're seeing a browser or server cache hit. In either case, the solution is quite simple: add a random number to the POST request of the form, or, if the controller is performing a redirect, add a random param there too.

I know it's not clean, but it's an easy and effective way to get around excessive caching.

If you can specify a correct expire header in your component, you might be able to solve the issue as well; but I don't know about the implementation of T3 cache - except that I had a bad time with it once.

Comment: I am very grateful for the suggestion of the random in the POST. I can see loads of other situations where this would be helpful too!